# Python: Multiple arguments being passed as a single argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, command-line, arguments

I'm using subprocess to use the command line and pass in arguments for another script. I have a list of arguments which I made into a string:

```
import subprocess as sp

arg_list = ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
arg_string = " ".join(arg_list)
```

Now this works well with the following output `arg1 arg2 arg3`. The problem is, when i pass it to the command line, it only recognizes this as one argument.

```
sp.call(["test_file.tcl", arg_string])
```

** Note: I'm using `call` only becasue this script needs to be Python 3.4

I know this is only one argument becasue adding the following to the .tcl file:

```
[lindex $argv 0]
[lindex $argv 1]
[lindex $argv 2]
```

The output is:

```
arg1 arg2 arg3
. (These are blank lines not dots)
.
```

Is this the correct approach? How can I make this work so that it actually gets recognized at 3 arguments instead of just 1?

** Answer:
Adding `shell=True` allows a string to be passed instead of a list.

```
sp.call("test_file.tcl {0}".format(arg_string), shell=True)
```

Comment: That's just what came to mind to pass a string into the `call` method.

Comment: `help(subprocess.call)` in a python interactive shell would have shown you how to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't join `args_list` to a string, then use the splat operator. This will pass `['test_file.tcl', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']` to `call`.

```
sp.call(["test_file.tcl", *arg_list])
```

Depending on your OS, you may need to pass `shell=True` as well.

Comment: thanks that helped me adding `shell=True`

Comment: Don't combine a list argument and `shell=True`. The whole point of passing a list is to *avoid* needing a shell. If you need a shell, you are probably better off constructing an appropriate string than letting `subprocess` try to build one from your list.